# Million of vertex/edges (don´t know exactly the name)

Tags: mesh

[image]well here´s the thing I´m new to blender and I started creating a model of a human figure which I will animate in the near future. Now I´m supposed to start with the retopology phase, which gets really annoying cause every time I select the edit mode, the surface of my model is full of these millions of vertex/edges/etc. which difficults my work cause it gets really confusing to create a retopology of my model.

P.S.: I´ve watched retopology tutorials on youtube in which the view of such mesh is disabled in edit mode to make the work easier https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VC98kiy10Q

Comment: What do you want to know? I can't understand. Do you need  a retopology tool?

Comment: I need to know how to not see the mesh on my model´s surface in edit mode.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's needed to enter Edit mode of *highpoly* often; when doing retopology you'll enter Edit mode for lowpoly. Still to make work faster hide parts of viewport either by clipping border or by **Mask** modifier added to highpoly. Probably it's worth looking at ZBrush which works better with high polycounts.

Comment: So you mean that I don´t need to enter the edit mode to do the retopology? Sorry if my english is not proper, it´s not my native language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(This answer is from before clarification was added. It is simply a list of ways you can retopologize your object. What he actually wants is something entirely different, and what he is asking for in the question (at the time of writing this) is impossible.)

You can try a **few** things.

1. **remove doubles**.

   - Go into **edit mode**.
   - Click, **remove doubles**.
2. **remesh** modifier

   - modifiers panel
   - "generate" section
   - "remesh"
3. **retopology tool**

   - [Retopoflow](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/retopoflow/)
4. **recreation**

   - Create a new mesh.
   - Simply start from scratch.
   - This time, follow the previous mesh as a guide.
   - Use your new mesh.
   - (You can then try to [bake in the detail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTGTUd0pCaQ) from your previous mesh)

---

Example of "remove doubles"

[image]

Example of "remesh"

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I explained myself well, but I got much more than other people told me, so...thank you so much.

Comment: I cannot purchase retopoflow right now thanks. All I want is to not see it. Like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VC98kiy10Q look at how he is in edit mode and yet the mesh is not visible, only the model. I just want to know how did he do that.

Comment: Oh, he's using an addon. The reason he doesn't see the vertices is that he's not really in edit mode (of that object). He has a new object, which he is creating (like in the last method I suggested) and is using the addon to help him create a new mesh, using the old one as a guide. Therefore, he is only in edit mode in his new mesh, and his old mesh is in object mode.

Comment: Oh! and how do i do that?

Comment: Just watch the whole video, and it should help. Or you can do it by hand, and follow the steps I gave for the last option (create a new object where you just use the old one as a reference, then bake in the detail). What I would do, is follow that tutorial to make a very simple mesh on top of you old one that still has the same shape, then use the link I provided, and bake in some extra detail. (set shading to smooth and use a subsurf to help smooth the mesh with fewer verts if you want)

Comment: Yeah I know but how do actually get to create a new mesh and use the old one as guide since the mesh from the old one won´t dissapear making the whole work hard?

Comment: I mean...you probably have already done that. The model totally clean from all that mess. And then create the new mesh.

Comment: Press shift+a, go in edit mode, "a", "x", delete vertices. Now shift+a, add a plane (in edit mode), and select one side and press e to extrude.
Make sure you notice that in the beginning of the video he makes a **new object**, goes in edit mode, and deletes everything. He is in edit mode on the new object, not the creature.

Comment: What I mean by "use it as a guide", is almost like what this guy does in this tutorial. Just use it like a 3D reference image. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT1GNMevfc
Or you can use the addon, as shown in the video you shared.

Comment: That vid you shared shows just how to do it. Follow exactly step by step and you should be good.

Comment: Yeah! think I get it now. I´ll try it.

Comment: You're welcome. :) I love to help people learn

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! THAAAANK YOUUUUUU! thanks for your patience :D :D :D

Comment: Okay, great! You're welcome. (for any future responders, you should take down the thread or accept an answer so they know you no longer need help.)

Answer (score 2):

So in light of your wrong retopo setup these are the steps you need to take.

**Prep High Poly mesh**
1. Turn off "show wires" and "draw all edges" on the high poly object.
2. Give this a dark color material with some soft specularity to aid in retopo work.

[image]

**Prep Low Poly mesh**
1. Create a new plane mesh to be your new low poly retopo object.
2. Turn on xray on the object property panel.
3. Turn on show face normals on the navigation panel in the 3d viewport.

**Prep Retopology tools**
1. Turn on snap tool, on the drop down menu choose "face"
2. Turn on "snap to self"
3. Turn on "project individual elements on the surface of other object"
4. Turn on "automatic merge vertices"

[image]

5. Learn the "F2 addon" or other addon suggested and use it to work retopology.

Here is the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: I already tried turning wire and draw all edges off, but thanks anyway.

Comment: You are doing retopology wrong then. The high poly object and the lowpoly retopology object should be 2 seperate meshes. They are not the same object. So when you enter edit mode you would only see the wire of the lowpoly object. and not the high poly one. You must have been trying to do retopology in the high poly mesh, and that is why it's a mess on your screen.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'll write here to be more clear. 
If you want to retopology your mesh, have good tutorial and don't see your high poly in edit mode use this tool, **Mira.**

Here the link to the tool [MIRA TOOL](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?366107-MiraTools)

Click on the link like i show in the picture

[image]

You'll download a zip. Open this zip and click on mifthtools-master, then click on blender, then click on addons. You'll see the folder mira tool like in this image

[image]

Take this folder and copy in the

Program/Blender foundation/2.76(the version of blender you have)/scripts/addons
(you have to put the folder mira here in addons)

Like that
[image]

Now it works!

This tool is free with a lot of tutorials and **let you retopology your high poly mesh in object mode**.

The tutorial will show you better but the point is: i add a plane that will be use to create the low poly mesh on the high poly one. **In this way you'll work easy in edit mode with the plane and not with your high poly**.

The mira panel is in the left side when you are in edit mode

[image]

Here a shot:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35882/discussion-on-answer-by-fuboski-million-of-vertex-edges-dont-know-exactly-the).